# localappdata for restricted user

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I want to write into the current user´s local AppData-Directory. InnoSetup comes with the {localappdata}-constant. But this won´t work in some cases: The constant points to the user that runs the setup. On a restricted account the user that runs the setup (administrator) is different to the user that is signed in (restricted user).

How can I get (at least the name) of the logged in windows user in innosetup that I can get (or build) the correct path?